# assigning willSet block to iOS isResting property

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, swift2, didset

I would like to set a `willSet` statement to **`isResting`** property. Whenever **`isResting`** is changed some function is called. This is what I mean:

```
starNode.physicsBody?.isResting: Bool = false{
    willSet{
       if newValue == true{
           print("GOOGOO")
       }else{
           print("STOP")
       }
   }
}
```

This is not working. Can you assign a willSet or didSet to an already defined iOS property? If not, how do I get similar effect?

This is the documentation:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012283
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsBody_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNPhysicsBody/isResting

Answer (score 1):

**If not read-only:**

One option would be to subclass the library object and override the property you'd like to set.  Then, you can implement `willSet` within your subclass:

```
class Object {
    var property: Float = 0.0
}


class ChildObject: Object {
    override var property: Float {
        willSet {
            print("Set in child class")

        }
    }
}
```

This is the way that Apple recommends in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) (see "Overriding Property Observers"):

> You can use property overriding to add property observers to an
>   inherited property. This enables you to be notified when the value of
>   an inherited property changes, regardless of how that property was
>   originally implemented.

**If read-only:**

You might be able to use [Key-Value Observing](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/11/swift-kvo-alternatives.html), if the object inherits from `NSObject`, or if it has been marked `dynamic` in Swift.

Comment: Can't do that, because isResting is a read-only property. Any other way to get notified when a property changes it's value?

Comment: @krompir2 -- You can possibly use Key-Value Observing (answer updated).  It might be helpful to expand your question to include *which* object you're looking at, which framework it comes from, and a link to the documentation.  It might be obvious to someone who does a lot of gaming/physics simulations, but that's not me, unfortunately.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

Is this property an IBInspectable property?
In Objetive-C this is automatically if this is a property trough getter and setter, but in Swift it isn't. You can make this property as private and create methods for set this property and inside this method, add a call for another method.

```
func setResting(resting:Bool) {
    self.isResting = resting
    //call another method here
}
```

Comment: This is a property from iOS frameworks. I didn't declare it. It was already declared by Apple and it's not IBInspectable. I would like to be notified whenever it's value changes.